# How can I scan my network to find the machines that are running as domain controllers?

Tags: logging, dns, active-directory, active-directory-group, domaincontroller

In my network, there are about 50,000 IP addresses. I wanted to run a scan and find out what machines are acting as a domain controller.

I can't WMI, neither I can read the registry files to find that information because I don't want to scan as an AD administrator.

Are there any logs I can see to identify a machine as a domain controller or is there any port open etc?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds somewhat off-topic here, unless you actually trying to script something or do this programiatically. You might get better advise over at [sf] in the mean time you should note that DNS uses port 53, that might help you get started, though if you don't want to scan as an AD Admin are you even allowed to do this? hitting 50,000 hosts on a network without the admin's approval may be trouble ahead for you...

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.

Comment: if I understood correctly, you want to identify domain controllers. You can do this by reading them directly from OU "Domain controllers" or by command: nltest / dclist:yourdomain